# Firefox has issue with printing the site

Tags: html, css, page-break, page-break-inside

So, I have this page which includes a table with a lot of rows, and needs to be printed as hard copy. Something strange happens when I print- or get a `PDF` output- from this page : after first page, the rest of the pages completely lose their `CSS` styles, such as font, color, table border, etc. 
This issue only happens in Firefox, and Chrome has no problem either with printing or `PDF` output. When I look at `print preview` in Firefox, everything seems fine, too.

This is how I managed to break my long table into pages. Is there any reason why it loses it's style after page break happens?

```
@media print {
    .table-striped{
      //my table
      page-break-inside:auto;
      tr{
        page-break-inside:avoid;
      }
    }
    .isPrint{
     //main div which wraps table
        page-break-inside: auto;
      }

    .table-bordered > thead > tr > th {
        background: #666 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }
    .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }
    .table.table-bordered tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
        background: #e5e5e5 !important;
       -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }
    .table-bordered > thead > tr > th, .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
        border: 1px solid #000 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }

}
```

EDIT: This is how my html code goes. I also added table classes to the css part above:

```
<article class="isPrint">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="font-family: mitraBold" ng-if="items.length > 0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>INDEX</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>      
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h1 class="text-center" ng-if="items.length <= 0">
    ERROR
  </h1>
</article>
```

Comment: Can you provide a short example of your HTML that you are trying to print?

Comment: @NickWyman sure, I added my html table and relative css codes to the question. Thanks for your attention.